Spouse name alterations on the last page
I have a valid b2 visa on an indian passport.  If i make corrections on the last page under spouse name column will my visa become invalid? Do i need to visit the us embassy and reapply?

Recently posted also: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/190124/spouse-name-alterations

The official Change of spouse’s name guidance says: What is the process to endorse spouse's name on my passport?
A: To endorse the spouse's name on your passport, you have to apply for a 'Re-issue' of passport and get the specified change done in personal particulars.
